# IBM Worklight Hybrid Application seems to stuck before initialize

Tags: ios, backbone.js, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm facing a strange problem with Worklight 6.2.0.1. It occurs only on iOS.

Sometimes when I launch the app it seems to get stuck, so I have to minimize and reopen it in order to continue the initialization flow.

**This is the Xcode Log:**

```
2015-07-29 16:33:02.693 SocialClosing[695:127943] [DEBUG] [WL_INIT] -[WLImpl initWL] in WLImpl.m:124 :: At first launch
2015-07-29 16:33:02.705 SocialClosing[695:127943] [DEBUG] [WL_INIT] -[WLImpl initWL] in WLImpl.m:150 :: Web resources should not be extracted.
2015-07-29 16:33:02.866 SocialClosing[695:127878] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2015-07-29 16:33:02.875 SocialClosing[695:127878] Unlimited access to network resources
2015-07-29 16:33:02.884 SocialClosing[695:127878] [CDVTimer][wlapp] 0.239968ms
2015-07-29 16:33:02.884 SocialClosing[695:127878] [CDVTimer][push] 0.120997ms
2015-07-29 16:33:02.884 SocialClosing[695:127878] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 0.899971ms
2015-07-29 16:33:02.896 SocialClosing[695:127878] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <Compatibility50ViewController: 0x15e81e60>.
2015-07-29 16:33:02.900 SocialClosing[695:127878] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2015-07-29 16:33:05.231 SocialClosing[695:127878] Finished load of: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E4ED8DED-718D-44BA-9B45-A1195F6F7AE4/SocialClosing.app/www/default/index.html
2015-07-29 16:33:06.887 SocialClosing[695:127903] [DEBUG] [NONE] ondeviceready event dispatched
2015-07-29 16:33:06.904 SocialClosing[695:127878] THREAD WARNING: ['WLApp'] took '17.299072' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2015-07-29 16:33:06.930 SocialClosing[695:127903] [WARN] [NONE] Initialization options 'enableLogger' and 'logger' are deprecated. Use WL.Logger.config to set logger behavior.
2015-07-29 16:33:06.934 SocialClosing[695:127878] log1
2015-07-29 16:33:06.935 SocialClosing[695:127906] [DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient init started
2015-07-29 16:33:06.940 SocialClosing[695:127904] [DEBUG] [NONE] CookieMgr read cookies: {}
2015-07-29 16:33:06.944 SocialClosing[695:127948] [DEBUG] [NONE] Read cookies: null
2015-07-29 16:33:06.963 SocialClosing[695:127878] THREAD WARNING: ['DeviceAuth'] took '17.553711' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2015-07-29 16:33:06.973 SocialClosing[695:127903] [DEBUG] [NONE] before: initOptions.onSuccess
2015-07-29 16:33:06.978 SocialClosing[695:127948] [DEBUG] [NONE] after: initOptions.onSuccess
2015-07-29 16:33:06.984 SocialClosing[695:127905] [DEBUG] [NONE] added onPause event handler 
2015-07-29 16:33:06.991 SocialClosing[695:127906] [DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient init success
```

**After I minimize and reopen the app (through the Home button on iOS device) it continue and run my javascript code, as you can see bellow:**

```
{2015-07-29 16:35:28.632 SocialClosing[695:127878] Login Initialized
2015-07-29 16:35:28.652 SocialClosing[695:127878] THREAD WARNING: ['NotificationEx'] took '18.151123' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2015-07-29 16:35:28.653 SocialClosing[695:127878] UserDAO initialize begin.
2015-07-29 16:35:28.654 SocialClosing[695:127878] BaseDAO initialize begin.
2015-07-29 16:35:28.654 SocialClosing[695:127878] BaseDAO _initializeJSONStoreCollection begin.
2015-07-29 16:35:41.795 SocialClosing[695:127878] JSONStore collection UserCollection opened successfully.
2015-07-29 16:35:42.695 SocialClosing[695:127878] UserPersistenceDAO initialize begin.
2015-07-29 16:35:42.696 SocialClosing[695:127878] BaseDAO initialize begin.
2015-07-29 16:35:42.696 SocialClosing[695:127878] BaseDAO _initializeJSONStoreCollection begin.
2015-07-29 16:35:44.281 SocialClosing[695:127878] JSONStore collection UserPersistenceCollection opened successfully.
2015-07-29 16:35:44.281 SocialClosing[695:127878] UserPersistenceDAO getUser begin.
2015-07-29 16:35:44.281 SocialClosing[695:127878] BaseDAO _getAllRegistries begin.
2015-07-29 16:35:45.931 SocialClosing[695:127878] Find All registries successfully executed on UserPersistenceCollection JSONStore.}
```

I have been trying to resolve this issue for over a week without success.

Here is some considerations:

- This problem is not happening every time;
- I'm debugging the app on a real device (iPad Air and iPhone 5c);
- I have debugged it on Safari and it seems to get stuck before call my
  pageview (I'm using backbone) initialize method;

Please, feel free to ask me more information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing the JSONStore initialization simply takes time. What happens what you try w/out initializing JSONStore? Is it faster?

Comment: I removed all JSONStore initialization and it still stuck.
See on log that it get the page and load it:

load of: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E4ED8DED-718D-44BA-9B45-A1195F6F7AE4/SocialClosing.app/www/default/index.html. 

But it does not fire the javascript initialization method.

I can see the login page displayed on iPad, but when i try to interact with it nothing happens. So, when i press the Home button and reopen the app, it works fine and call the initialization method from the javascript file.

Comment: You'll need to provide you Worklight project (from Eclipse, export it) so it could be debugged.

Comment: How can i provide you the Worklight Project? I can't put it here. I'm a IBM Employee, maybe we can talk on ST.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing an answer for my question, but it's not the full solution.

As I'm using Require JS to manage dependencies, I let it to handle the following Worklight files:

- initOptions.js
- main.js
- messages.js

Now the JsonStore is initializing correctly, but sometimes i get this:

```
2015-08-18 11:12:39.373 SocialClosing[2387:711665] [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth
2015-08-18 11:12:39.379 SocialClosing[2387:711640] [WARN] [USER_CERT_AUTH] +[WLUserAuthManager getCertificateIdentifier] in WLUserAuthManager.m:68 :: Certificate Identifier Key: com.worklight.userenrollment.certificate:com.ibm.cio.be.SocialClosing
2015-08-18 11:12:39.387 SocialClosing[2387:711640] THREAD WARNING: ['UserAuth'] took '11.081055' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2015-08-18 11:12:39.388 SocialClosing[2387:711640] Error in error callback: UserAuth318076151 = TypeError: null is not a valid argument for 'in' (evaluating 'field in profile')
```

In this cases, the splash screen does not disappear.

Unfortunately until now i don't know how to solve this problem.